# error message of undefined reference to `WinMain@16' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, visual-studio-code

I am running a C program using `vscode`, and got the following error message, and there is no information provided by terminal panel.

```
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\ccG7tsTb.o:fi_evaluation.c:(.text+0x3d9d): undefined reference to `rotation'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16' 
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[image]

Comment: have you done a search on SO, this version 50 of the same question

Comment: Hi, would you like to explain more on the comments, what does SO mean?  Thanks.